# How do I start non-GUI Emacs on the commandline?

Tags: terminal-emacs, start-up, gui-emacs, command-line-arguments

How do I start non-GUI Emacs on the commandline?

`emacs-no-x11` doesn't seem to be in recent Emacs versions.

Comment: `emacs -nw` will do that. `man emacs` says: `              -nw, --no-window-system
                      Tell  Emacs  not  to  create a graphical frame.  If you use this switch
                      when invoking Emacs from an xterm(1) window, display is  done  in  that
                      window.
`

Comment: @Geremia: Where did you see `emacs-no-x11` ?

Comment: @phils [The SlackBuild script for packaging it in Slackware](https://mirror.slackbuilds.org/slackware/slackware64-current/source/e/emacs/emacs.SlackBuild) made an `emacs-no-X11` binary.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Possibly that's only ever been a Slackware thing; certainly it's not a standard executable name for Emacs in general.  In case it's useful information, the likes of Debian provide separate packages (e.g. `emacs-nox`) for installing a build of Emacs which has no GUI support at all (so no need to use `-nw`) for any users who *never* want the GUI (or who just don't have X installed).

Answer (score 1):

> `emacs -nw` will do that. `man emacs` says:
>
> ```
> -nw, --no-window-system
>         Tell Emacs not to create a graphical frame.
>         If you use this switch when invoking Emacs
>         from an xterm(1) window, display is done in
>         that window.
> ```

<sup>-tip [NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80446/how-do-i-start-non-gui-emacs-on-the-commandline?noredirect=1#comment135051_80446) above</sup>